# nifi stream csv file to hdfs

Tags: csv, hadoop, hdfs, apache-nifi

## Scenario

I'm trying to do research on store realtime update csv file to HDFS with NiFi. I have 2 files, `kafka2hdfs.csv` and `test_csv.csv`. Both contains same information as

```
a,b,c,d,e
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3
a4,b4,c4,d4,e4
a5,b5,c5,d5,e5
a6,b6,c6,d6,e6
a7,b7,c7,d7,e7
a8,b8,c8,d8,e8
```

I'm using `filebeat` to transmit the file to `nifi`. Just few rows `filebeat` will reach the bottom real soon.
filebeat

```
2020-07-15T16:07:32.061+0700    DEBUG   [harvester]     log/log.go:107  End of file reached: C:\Program Files\Filebeat\test-kafka\test_csv.csv; Backoff now.
2020-07-15T16:07:32.090+0700    DEBUG   [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:404      Registry file updated. 2 states written.
2020-07-15T16:07:32.091+0700    DEBUG   [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:356      Processing 1 events
2020-07-15T16:07:32.093+0700    DEBUG   [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:326      Registrar state updates processed. Count: 1
2020-07-15T16:07:32.093+0700    DEBUG   [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:411      Write registry file: C:\Program Files\Filebeat\data\registry\filebeat\data.json (2)
2020-07-15T16:07:32.140+0700    DEBUG   [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:404      Registry file updated. 2 states written.
2020-07-15T16:07:33.013+0700    INFO    [publisher_pipeline_output]     pipeline/output.go:101  Connecting to backoff(async(tcp://10.64.2.236:5044))
2020-07-15T16:07:33.013+0700    DEBUG   [logstash]      logstash/async.go:119   connect
2020-07-15T16:07:33.031+0700    INFO    [publisher_pipeline_output]     pipeline/output.go:111  Connection to backoff(async(tcp://10.64.2.236:5044)) established
2020-07-15T16:07:33.036+0700    DEBUG   [logstash]      logstash/async.go:171   17 events out of 17 events sent to logstash host 10.64.2.236:5044. Continue sending
2020-07-15T16:07:33.042+0700    DEBUG   [harvester]     log/log.go:107  End of file reached: C:\Program Files\Filebeat\test-kafka\kafka2hdfs.csv; Backoff now.
```

and it successfully created file on hdfs

```
hadoop@ambari:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/test
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        114 2020-07-15 16:07 /user/test/kafka2hdfs.csv
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        129 2020-07-15 16:06 /user/test/test_csv.csv
hadoop@ambari:~$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/test/test_csv.csv
a,b,c,d,e
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3
a4,b4,c4,d4,e4
a5,b5,c5,d5,e5
a6,b6,c6,d6,e6
a7,b7,c7,d7,e7
a8,b8,c8,d8,e8
```

now I'm trying to update `test_csv.csv` file into

```
a,b,c,d,e
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3
a4,b4,c4,d4,e4
a5,b5,c5,d5,e5
a6,b6,c6,d6,e6
a7,b7,c7,d7,e7
a8,b8,c8,d8,e8
9,9,9,9,9
10,10,10,10,10
```

and then rerun it, but on hdfs it wasnt updated. Filebeat sent the data actually

```
2020-07-15T16:26:54.892+0700    DEBUG   [processors]    processing/processors.go:187      Publish event: {
  "@timestamp": "2020-07-15T09:26:54.892Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "7.7.1"
  },
  "message": "10,10,10,10,10",
  "log": {
    "offset": 150,
    "file": {
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\test-kafka\\test_csv.csv"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "type": "log"
  },
  "ecs": {
    "version": "1.5.0"
  },
  "host": {
    "name": "name"
  },
  "agent": {
    "hostname": "name",
    "id": "5e2fec03-bbdc-4f91-acc9-4ab36c7268db",
    "version": "7.7.1",
    "type": "filebeat",
    "ephemeral_id": "e1f3e6e0-f4f5-4f68-ad1d-8bb1767e4d4a"
  }
}
```

```
hadoop@ambari:~$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/test/test_csv.csv
a,b,c,d,e
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3
a4,b4,c4,d4,e4
a5,b5,c5,d5,e5
a6,b6,c6,d6,e6
a7,b7,c7,d7,e7
a8,b8,c8,d8,e8
```

### Architecture

CSV - Filebeat - NiFi - HDFS

### Nifi

[image: nifi architecture]

## Expectation

I thought nifi will update earlier generated file in hdfs to the latest edit. But it wasn't.

```
9,9,9,9,9
```

but there wasnt not 9,9,9,9,9 on test_csv.csv in `hdfs`

## Questions

1. Is it possible to do so with NiFi?
2. Did I miss any processor?

Comment: What is the logic behind the 9,9,9,9,9
10,10,10,10,10 in the csv ?

Comment: why you dont continue the flow after the putHDFS ? instead of getfile back to flowfile

Comment: Dear Maxime G, thank you so much for your reply. There are no algorithm to the file. I just simulate it as if some update added to file. Since i expected it to stream realtime data, but it wasn't. What do you mean with "why you dont continue the flow after the putHDFS ? instead of getfile back to flowfile" can you explain it more please. Thank you

Comment: maybe i miss understood something, but maybe dont auto-terminate your putHDFS processor and make the update to the flowfile and put it back to HDFS.

Comment: Dear maxime, I'm really sorry for late reply, but i get what you mean. I dont auto-terminate the processor. after the first run it still running, on the second run it still running.   How do you mean by your statement? Can you explain it each with processor? Thank you so much for your kind respond